# How to prevent that the keyboard hides my EditText?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I have a RelativeLayout at the top, then below i have a ListView in the center and finally at the bottom i have another relativeLayout with an EditText and a Button inside.

I want the ListView to resize when I click on the EditText and the IME(virtual keyboard) appears. If i put adjustResize in the manifest, the Listview is resized to leave space for the IME, but the RelativeLayout with the EditText that is below is covered by the IME and I can't see what I'm writing. If I put adjustPan, the keyboard pushs up all, the ListView is not resized and i loose the top RelativeLayout.

My Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/application_background"
    android:paddingLeft="15px"
    android:paddingRight="15px"
    android:paddingTop="15px"
    android:paddingBottom="15px">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlyParentPost"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="450px"
        android:layout_height="85px"
        android:background="@drawable/app_gradient_color"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgUserOfParent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px"
            android:background="@drawable/userfeed"
            android:layout_width="64px"
            android:layout_height="64px"
            android:layout_below="@+id/logoImg">
        </ImageView>
        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/logoImg"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgUserOfParent"
            android:id="@+id/lblNameOfParent"
            android:textSize="17px"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblNameOfParent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgUserOfParent"
            android:id="@+id/lblBodyOfParent"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="17px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblBodyOfParent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgUserOfParent"
            android:id="@+id/lblDateOfParent"
            android:textColor="#70ccff"
            android:textSize="11px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rlyParentPost"
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout">

     <ListView
       android:isScrollContainer="true"
         android:id="@+id/lsvComments"
         android:layout_height="515px"
         android:layout_width="450px"
         android:background="#ffffff"
         android:listSelector="@drawable/multi_white_color"
         android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
         android:divider="#9aa5ac"
         android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
         android:dividerHeight="1px">
     </ListView>

     <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:padding="5dip"
         android:layout_below="@+id/lsvComments"
         android:background="@drawable/app_gradient_comments"
         android:id="@+id/contentLayout">
         <EditText
             android:inputType="text"
             android:id="@+id/txtComment"
             android:hint="What are you working on?" 
             android:textSize="22px"
             android:layout_marginLeft="8px"
             android:layout_height="72px"
             android:layout_width="344px">
         </EditText>
         <Button
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtComment"
             android:id="@+id/cmdShare"
             android:layout_width="79px"
             android:layout_height="65px"
             android:background="@drawable/feed_comments_multi_stage"
             android:layout_marginLeft="7px">
         </Button>
    </RelativeLayout> 
   </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not be setting your layout_width and layout_heights with explicit pixel values.  Instead, use wrap_parent or fill_parent as appropriate.

If you want somethign like a text view to be a particular width, use dpi units which will adjust correctly on different screen resolutions.

Regarding your specific virtual keyboard problem,  I would try setting up the ListView so it takes up the remaining space.

--Set the heights of everything except the ListView to wrap_parent
--Set the ListView to fill_parent,

The ListView should take up however much space is available, and thus shrink when you ask it to resize.

Comment: Thanks Mayra by the response, I tried do what you say.. I put all in wrap_content except the listview which i put in fill_parent. But when i start the activity i only saw the first layout in the top and the listview below which filled all the rest of the screen, but i lost the bottom layout with the EditText, so i couldn't even click the edittext to show the keyboard

Comment: Your layout references are using "@+id". When you specify that something is below, next to, etc, something else, the view that you're setting it relative to has to come first. And you have to give it an ID that's already been declared using `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtComment"

Comment: It looks like you should be able to change your outer RelativeLayout to just be a LinearLayout with orientation="vertical".  Also, a good tool for debugging layouts is the HeirarchyViewer, in the tools directory of the sdk.  It will visualize how it thinks the layout is.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I found a solution.
In my case, in the Manifeste.xml, I declared a minSdkVersion=3 (Android 1.5), and my project was compiled with Android 2.2 (SDK 8).In theory, it should work... but not!
I modified minsdkVersion to 4 (Android 1.6), then it's OK.
It was just an compatibily issue between the different Android SDK.
Good luck to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! With minSdkVersion set to 3, I had the soft keyboard partially obscuring the bottom of a TextEdit widget, but setting it to 4 fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

if you by any chance are using this:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

this can cause the problem.  I originally added that line to fix a bug where the status bar pushes the app downward... but it also prevents the keyboard from pushing the app upward.

sigh.

Answer (score 1):

U can add a scrollview like this :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">

..........


</ScrollView>
```

This would cause the app to focus on the edit text and adjust it to focus on screen ! it also works inside fragments!

Answer (score 0):

If EditText Field is been covered by the KeyBoard Use the following code:

```
EditText= findViewById(R.id.edittext)
EditText?.getParent()?.requestChildFocus(EditText,EditText)
```

If you want the *Cursor* to be in the Focused EditText than use  `EditText.requestFocus()` *after* the `EditText?.getParent()?.requestChildFocus(EditText,EditText)` which helps to get the focus and Cursor in the Focused EditText.