# Shrinking a ScrollView on resize for IME - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, resize, scrollview, android-softkeyboard, ime

I'm trying to get the following ScrollView to shrink down so that all the other elements above it will still be visible when using the IME, or, at the very least, so that the top of the ScrollView is moved down to the top of the screen.

Main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/gameLayout">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/gameTitle" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="@color/Red"
        android:maxLines="1" />

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/gameScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="false" android:layout_above="@+id/gameEntry"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gameTitle">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/gameText" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </ScrollView>

    <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/gameEntry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/gameSubmit"
        android:hint="@string/Hint" android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:lines="1" />


    <TextView android:id="@+id/gameSubmit" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/gameEntry"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Submit" android:textColor="@color/Red"
        android:textSize="18dp" android:lines="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can this be done?
I probably made some stupid mistake... Oh, I did everything they recommended on [How to prevent that the keyboard hides my EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478601/how-to-prevent-that-the-keyboard-hides-my-edittext)

And, I also added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to the manifest, and it's still panning... Cue the "wow that's a silly question" in 3..2..1......

Comment: Did you ever fix this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure... I dropped that project, since that was a school project.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` on the `ScrollView` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and adding `android:layout_above="@+id/gameEntry"` to the `ScrollView`.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work.  I had `android:layout_above="@+id/gameEntry`, and I'd tried wrap_content, but that didn't work either.  Thanks, though.